# Indexing does not stop on particular project (PhpStorm)

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

I am using PhpStorm from a couple of months, everything was working fine. Yesterday I have just cloned a new repository and started a new project and indexing is not completed or finished for a particular project.

I have already used the technique to invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: Are there any symlinks that would create a loop within the project directory? Are there any errors in Help > Show Log in ... > idea.log?

Comment: the Problem is solved by excluding folders that are not required an more